# SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 102

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I created a simple node/express api connected to mongo atlas, i try to send post requests to add new data to the database with rest client extension in vscode but keep on running into the above error not sure where I have messed up in my code

main server file with middleware

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const coolapi = require("./api/coolapi");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_ACCESS, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, () => {
  console.log("DB connected");
});

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/coolapi", coolapi);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server is running");
});
```

File with express Router

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const coolioObj = require("../models/CoolModel");

router.post("/signup", (request, response) => {
  const coolPerson = new coolioObj({
    username: request.body.username,
    email: request.body.email,
    password: request.body.password,
  });
  coolPerson
    .save()
    .then((data) => {
      response.json(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      response.json(error);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

file with mongoose schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const coolioSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("coolioDB", coolioSchema);
```

request being sent

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/coolapi/signup http/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username":"samthingsoweto",
    "email":"sams@amapiano.co",
    "password":"KabzaDaSmall",
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON arrays doesn't support a comma after the last item. That is the cause of the error. Delete the last comma in all JSON arrays.

```
 date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  }, <---
```

```
{
    "username":"peoplefrom",
    "email":"peopleperson@email.com",
    "password":"peoplepassword123", <---
}
```